# Can't convert Resource to string using TypeConverter

Tags: wpf, resources, typeconverter

Exception:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Text' to object of type
>   'System.String'. Unable to cast object
>   of type 'MyApp.Foo' to type
>   'System.String'.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <my:Foo x:Key="foo"></my:Foo>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{DynamicResource foo}"></TextBox>
```

C#

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {}
}

public class FooConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need to use a value converter there instead of a type converter.

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>  
    <my:Foo x:Key="foo"/>
    <my:FooConverter x:Key="fooConverter />
</Window.Resources>
<TextBox Text="{DynamicResource foo, Converter={DynamicResource fooConverter}}"></TextBox>
```

C#

```
public class FooConverter : IValueConverter
{ 
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
          return ((Foo)value).ToString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: This was a right direction. It works with Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource fooConverter}, Source={StaticResource foo}, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: How to achive same results without XAML?